# How get full length of date for Datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I need a column for the df that will be used to group it by weeks.

The problem is all the reports in Tableau are build using the following format for week: `2019-01-01` it is like, using the first day of week repetitively  Mon-Sun.

Data:

```
cw = pd.DataFrame({  "lead_date" : [2019-01-01 00:02:16, 2018-08-01 00:02:16 , 2017-07-07 00:02:16,  2015-12-01 00:02:16, 2016-09-01 00:02:16] ,
                    "name": ["aa","bb","cc", "dd", "EE"]  )}
```

My code:

```
# extracting 
cw["week"] = cw["lead_date"].apply(lambda df: df.strftime("%W") )
cw["month"] = cw["lead_date"].apply(lambda df: df.strftime("%m") )
cw["year"] = cw["lead_date"].apply(lambda df: df.strftime("%Y") )
```

Output:

```
lead_date            year   month  week
2019-01-01 00:02:16, 2019 ,  01  , 00
-
-
-
etc..
```

### Desired output:

having week as date format rather then just `00 or 01 etc..`

```
lead_date            year   month  week
2019-01-01 00:02:16, 2019 ,  01  , 2019-01-01
2019-01-15 00:02:16, 2019 ,  01  , 2019-01-14
2019-01-25 00:02:16, 2019 ,  01  , 2019-01-21
2019-01-28 00:02:16, 2019 ,  01  , 2019-01-21
```

Comment: Your "week" is actually a *date* indicating a particular week; does that help?

Comment: @ScottHunter, yes It is, the problem is all the reportins in Tableau are build using the following format for week: ```2019-01-01``` it is like, using the first day of week repetitively  Mon-Sun.

Comment: @Peter I see, that you want the first day of the week, so I made it that way in my answer, however 2019.01.01 is actually not the first day of that week as your required in your list.

Comment: @Geeocode, thank you, lol I didnt checked the data ``` 2019.01.01```, but yeah fist day of week. going to trying the code now

Comment: @Geocode, so ideally the last week of year should be like a short week for example 
```
lead_date   week
12/29/19     12/29/19
30/29/19     12/29/19
31/29/19     12/29/19
01/01/20      01/01/20
 ```

Comment: @Peter Ok, no problem, so I updated my answer and output.

Comment: @Geeocode, getting the following error: ```ValueError: The dtype of 'values' is incorrect. Must be 'datetime64[ns]'. Got datetime64[D] instead.```

Comment: I guess you passed incorrect date form to DatetimeIndex, could you give the full error message?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204751/discussion-between-peter-and-geeocode).

Comment: I am in the chatroom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows with using [pandas.DatetimeIndex.dayofweek](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timedeltas.html#time-deltas) and [pandas.Timedelta()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.dayofweek.html#pandas-datetimeindex-dayofweek)

(Note that the first day of `2019.01.01.` week is `2018.12.31.`):

```
    import pandas as pd

    cw = pd.DataFrame({"lead_date" : pd.DatetimeIndex([
                    "2019-01-01 00:02:16", "2018-08-01 00:02:16" , "2017-07-07 00:02:16",  
                    "2015-12-01 00:02:16", "2016-09-01 00:02:16"]),
                    "name": ["aa","bb","cc", "dd", "EE"]})  
    # extracting 
    cw["month"] = cw["lead_date"].apply(lambda df: df.strftime("%m") )
    cw["year"] = cw["lead_date"].apply(lambda df: df.strftime("%Y") )
    cw["week"] = (cw["lead_date"] - ((cw["lead_date"].dt.dayofweek) * 
                                     pd.Timedelta(days=1)).values.astype('M8[D]'))

    print(cw[["lead_date", "year", "month", "week"]])
```

**Out:**

```
            lead_date  year month       week
0 2019-01-01 00:02:16  2019    01 2018-12-31
1 2018-08-01 00:02:16  2018    08 2018-07-30
2 2017-07-07 00:02:16  2017    07 2017-07-03
3 2015-12-01 00:02:16  2015    12 2015-11-30
4 2016-09-01 00:02:16  2016    09 2016-08-29
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
cw['lead_date'].apply(lambda r: datetime.strptime(r, '%Y-%m-%d') - timedelta(days=datetime.strptime(r, '%Y-%m-%d').weekday()))
```

This will set every date to starting day of that week.

Answer (score 1):

I think this gets you the output you want:

```
cw = pd.DataFrame({  "lead_date" : [pd.to_datetime('2019-01-01 00:02:16'), pd.to_datetime('2018-08-01 00:02:16') , pd.to_datetime('2017-07-07 00:02:16'),  pd.to_datetime('2015-12-01 00:02:16'), pd.to_datetime('2016-09-01 00:02:16')] ,
                    "name": ["aa","bb","cc", "dd", "EE"]  })

cw["year"] = cw["lead_date"].apply(lambda df: df.strftime("%Y") )
cw["month"] = cw["lead_date"].apply(lambda df: df.strftime("%m") )
cw["week"] = cw["lead_date"].apply(lambda df: df.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") )
cw.drop(columns='name', inplace=True)
```

output:

```
            lead_date  year month        week
0 2019-01-01 00:02:16  2019    01  2019-01-01
1 2018-08-01 00:02:16  2018    08  2018-08-01
2 2017-07-07 00:02:16  2017    07  2017-07-07
3 2015-12-01 00:02:16  2015    12  2015-12-01
4 2016-09-01 00:02:16  2016    09  2016-09-01
```